# How do I find the name of someone who has multiple entries in a different table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out how to get through this type of scenario:

I have a Table A with names of people along with their IDs.  I have a Table B with the people's IDs and the type of car that they bought from this dealership.  Multiple people can have multiple entries if they buy multiple cars.

Let's say that David with ID 789 has bought multiple cars from this dealership, so he has multiple entries in Table B:

```
(ID  | Car)
(----|----)
(789 | Toyota)
(789 | Ford)
```

I want to query these tables so that my results show all of the people who have bought a Toyota, but not a Ford.

```
SELECT name, id
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.id where Car = 'Toyota') AND
a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id where Car = 'Ford')
```

I want to understand why this code does not bring back the ids who have bought a toyota but not a ford, even if they bought multiple cars?  What about the logic am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you just use `SELECT id where Car =...` in your where clause because b.id isn't a table header.

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: What if you put the where before the join?

Comment: You are not correlating the name IDs

Answer (score 0):

To start with the why it isn't working, SQL is evaluating the WHERE clause sections in pieces. When it evaluates `WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.id where Car = 'Toyota')`, all that remains in the table is records where that ID had Toyota since you are using relative subqueries. So, when it passes to the `AND a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id where Car = 'Ford')`, there are no remaining records with Ford in it.

This fiddle should help to illustrate what's happening - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=085cdad84898f4e498aa9a2e76947d93

The quick fix to this would be to use absolute references to TableB instead of a relative reference in the subquery as shown in this fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f95e3ef0ddab5290ee7b9fa13e7451ab